# what is the meaning of putting puts(" "); at the bottom of the following code?

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int arr [3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int i,j;
    
         for(i =0;i<3;i++)

        {
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)

           {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
            }
     
         puts("");
         return 0;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to understand the meaning of "puts("")?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_puts.htm

Comment: The `puts()` is there to add a newline each 3 printed values. But the program is wrong, because miss a closing brace. It should have been coded as `putchar('\n')`. Also the space is unnecessary to print the newline.

Answer (score 4):

`puts("")` prints nothing, followed by a newline. The prior `printf`s don't add a newline, so `puts("")` ends each line after each set of three `printf`s. You could achieve the same effect rather more directly with `putchar('\n')`, and it's generally a clearer way to go about this.

It's also important for ensuring the terminal's prompt will appear on a separate line, not immediately following the output after the program exits; even without the loop, if all the program's output appeared on a single line and no newline was printed, you'd get some ugly effects on most UNIX-y shell setups.